# How to send JSON OBJECT as a parameter in Retrofit 2 (Android)

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
@GET
Call<List<User>> getMyFriends(@Header(GlobalDeclarationsRetrofit.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION) String lang, @Url String url, "Need to send a json object here");
```

Any help should be greately appreciated..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send parameter as hashmap or pojo, the parameters will send as JSON object. as:

```
@POST("user/checkloc")
Call<CheckLocation> checkLocation(@Body Location location);
```

Here location is pojo object as:

```
public class Location {
String lat,lng;

    public Location(String lat, String lng) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}
```

and it will send parameters as JSON object as:

```
D/OkHttp﹕ --> POST /api/index.php/user/checkloc HTTP/1.1
D/OkHttp﹕    {"lat":"28.4792293","lng":"77.043042"}
```

You can also send parameter as Hashmap:

```
@POST("user/checkloc")
Call<CheckLocation> checkLocation(@Body HashMap<String, String> hashMap);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can I send other parameters along with Body. For example url, header along with Body.

Comment: checkLocation(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Body Location location);